# How can I filter for multiple object identifiers using the equivalent of wildcards or alternation in jq?

Tags: json, wildcard, jq, alternation

### Summary

I have a working [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) filter which correctly parses three different *name* and *payload* objects and massages them into the desired output format. The problem is that I'm having to express each object path explicitly, as I can't see to find a way to express alternation within the object identifiers.

I would like the filter to be more flexible so that it can show the data structure from `containers` down to any package manager with a title that starts with `Packages`. I need the whole structure, though, and not just the terminal nodes.

What I *think* I need is to express my object identifiers with alternation or wildcards, such as:

- `.capabilities.*.payload?`
- `.capabilities.([apk, dpkg, rpm]).payload?`

I realize neither of the above is valid jq syntax, which is the reason for the question. I have included a test corpus with valid JSON immediately below, and my current jq filter is listed in the section below that.

### Minimal JSON File

This is my test corpus, stored as *minimal.json* in the current directory.

```
{
  "containers": {
    "3dc76c82e566a116e5b64bc91a0b6220c71db7052f68317ebbe90521db55bf36": {
      "container_name": "/apache-46869",
      "capabilities": {
        "apk": {
          "title": "Packages (APK)"
        },
        "dpkg": {
          "title": "Packages (DPKG)",
          "payload": {
            "apt": "1.0.9.8.4",
            "libnghttp2-14": "1.18.1-1"
          }
        },
        "rpm": {
          "title": "Packages (RPM)"
        }
      }
    },
    "474047a1fe238e39fa1917aff0c93154624bbf159d321d49d5e685302589ab51": {
      "container_name": "/nginx-alpine-46869",
      "capabilities": {
        "apk": {
          "title": "Packages (APK)",
          "payload": {
            ".nginx-rundeps": "0",
            "apk-tools": "2.6.8-r2"
          }
        },
        "dpkg": {
          "title": "Packages (DPKG)"
        },
        "rpm": {
          "title": "Packages (RPM)"
        }
      }
    },
    "d7dcd90791240d78022941cf054a6b474f5329acd79aa15b58dc342f95a8ce33": {
      "container_name": "/apache-alpine-46869",
      "capabilities": {
        "apk": {
          "title": "Packages (APK)",
          "payload": {
            ".httpd-rundeps": "0",
            "apk-tools": "2.6.8-r2",
            "apr": "1.5.2-r1",
            "apr-util": "1.5.4-r2"
          }
        },
        "dpkg": {
          "title": "Packages (DPKG)"
        },
        "rpm": {
          "title": "Packages (RPM)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Explicit jq Filter

This is my current filter, which works but explicitly defines each [optional object indentifier-index](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters).

```
jq '
    [ .containers[] | { 
        name: .container_name, package_inventory: {
            apk: .capabilities.apk.payload?,
            dpkg: .capabilities.dpkg.payload?,
            rpm: .capabilities.rpm.payload?
        }   
    }]  
' minimal.json
```

### Expected Output

My current output (shown below) is correct. The goal isn't to fix the output, but rather to make the filter more flexible.

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "name": "/apache-46869",
>     "package_inventory": {
>       "apk": null,
>       "dpkg": {
>         "apt": "1.0.9.8.4",
>         "libnghttp2-14": "1.18.1-1"
>       },
>       "rpm": null
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "name": "/nginx-alpine-46869",
>     "package_inventory": {
>       "apk": {
>         ".nginx-rundeps": "0",
>         "apk-tools": "2.6.8-r2"
>       },
>       "dpkg": null,
>       "rpm": null
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "name": "/apache-alpine-46869",
>     "package_inventory": {
>       "apk": {
>         ".httpd-rundeps": "0",
>         "apk-tools": "2.6.8-r2",
>         "apr": "1.5.2-r1",
>         "apr-util": "1.5.4-r2"
>       },
>       "dpkg": null,
>       "rpm": null
>     }
>   }
> ]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to define a helper function.  If, for example, you write:

```
def payloads(keys): . as $in
  | reduce keys[] as $key ({}; .[$key] = ($in|.[$key].payload?) );
```

then your query becomes:

```
.containers[] | { 
    name: .container_name,
    package_inventory: (.capabilities | payloads( ["apk","dpkg","rpm"] ))
}
```

Other variants of course are also possible. For example, you could define `payloads` as an arity-2 function, and thereby pass in "capabilities".

#### Using a JSON object to specify the keys

Here is a variant of `payloads/1` illustrating (a) how to avoid `reduce`, and (b) how the keys can be specified by giving a JSON object as template:

```
def payloads_at(object):
  . as $in
  | object as $object
  | ({}
     | [($object|keys_unsorted[]) as $key
        | .[$key] = ($in|.[$key].payload?) ])
  | add;
```

This could be called like so: payloads_at( {apk, dpkg, rpm} ), or if you want the keys to be dynamically determined:

```
(.capabilities | payloads_at( . ) )
```

Comment: This seems to work, although I'm not entirely sure I fully understand *why*. It certainly appears to solve for the use case of alternation when I know the package types ahead of time, but is it also possible to solve for an arbitrary package type too? In other words, can it be made to work more like a wildcard than a whitelist of selectors?

Comment: You can use `keys` (or `keys_unsorted`) to generate an array of keys; better yet, using payload_at/1, you can pass in any object with the desired keys, e.g. an object at `.capabilties`.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This helper function is perhaps closer to what you're looking for:

```
def star(pre; template; post):
  pre as $object
  | ({} | [($object|template|keys_unsorted[]) as $key | .[$key] = ($object | .[$key] | post) ])
  | add;
```

#### Usage

Explicit list of key names:

```
star(.capabilities; {apk,dpkg,rpm}; .payload)
```

Keys of .capabilities:

```
star(.capabilities; .; .payload)
```

#### Example:

```
.containers[] | { 
    name: .container_name,
    package_inventory: star(.capabilities; .; .payload)
}
```